# React and MSGraph - send email

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-api

I'm having a hard time understanding how to send an email in react using msgraph.  I have authentication working through MSal and can show the user profile.  I have read the documentation and it feels like I'm missing many steps.  Does anyone know of a sample project that authenticates and sends a test email? Ultimately I would like to create a reusable function that takes in the TO, Subject, Body.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript

Comment: Hi, Thanks but I read that and still am having issues.  The documentation talks about using a authProvider but when I look at that I'm still missing something

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please Check this MS document that may help you to Sign in users and call the Microsoft Graph API from a React single-page app (SPA) using auth code flow : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-react . in this app you can write code for send email using the above document provided by Diveyesh

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reaching out.

Refer to the module [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-reactspa).

This module will introduce you to working with the Microsoft Graph in creating a React single-page application to access data in Office 365.

Thanks.